# Write Html with a Link to the view from the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a link in my view using a string from code behind like this, but it doesn't work. What is the way to generate HTML from code behind?

`@ViewBag.MessageFailedProject = "Unable to save changes. The project was deleted by another user. Click " + new HtmlString("<a href=\"/Project\">here</a>").ToHtmlString() + " to return to the project list";`

Using this way, the final result is:
Unable to save changes. The project was deleted by another user. Click < a href="/Project">here to return to the project list

Comment: Are you tried to debug to understand what don't work?

Comment: MVC doesn't use code behinds... what do you mean?

Comment: From the controller I try to write HTML to show in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In controller:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    ViewBag.MessageFailedProject = 
        "Unable to save changes. "+
        "The project was deleted by another user. "+
        "Click <a href=\"/Project\">here</a>  to return to the project list";

    return View();
}
```

in view:

```
@Html.Raw(@ViewBag.MessageFailedProject)
```

and it shows:

> Unable to save changes. The project was deleted by another user. Click [here](http://example.com/Project/) to return to the project list

All seems fine to me..

Comment: What was missing was the @Html.Raw(@ViewBag.MessageFailedProject)